# Spannabe String text from Bundle getExtras

Tags: java, android, notification-listener

In my notification listener, I m not able to get value for keyvalue
`[android.text]` when the notifications are received from gmail. It is working fine for most of notifications, but for gmail, it throws exception as below.

```
W/Bundle: Key android.text expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Below is how i m fetching value of text

```
String rawmessage = bundle.getString("android.text");
```

since we do not have any method for extracting SpannableString from bundle, can someone help to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this-->

`String rawmessage = bundle.getCharSequence("android.text");`

Or try it like this-->

```
SpannableString a = (SpannableString) bundle.getCharSequence("android.text");
yourview.setText(a)
```